# ERESOLVE cound not resolve error when running npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, vite, sveltekit

I'm having really difficult time resolving dependency conflicts when installing and updating npm packages. The console error is as below. I tried installing legacy deps and reinstalling some modules but none seems working.

Could someone help me how to resolve this conflicts ? What to delete/reinstall/update ?

edit: using sveltekit latest version

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.454
npm ERR! Found: vite@2.9.15
npm ERR! node_modules/vite
npm ERR!   dev vite@"^2.9.15" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vite@"^3.1.0-beta.1" from @sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.454
npm ERR! node_modules/@sveltejs/kit
npm ERR!   dev @sveltejs/kit@"next" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: vite@3.1.0-beta.1
npm ERR! node_modules/vite
npm ERR!   peer vite@"^3.1.0-beta.1" from @sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.454
npm ERR!   node_modules/@sveltejs/kit
npm ERR!     dev @sveltejs/kit@"next" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/krystian/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/krystian/.npm/_logs/2022-08-30T19_09_07_228Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: did you remember to remove nodemodules before reinstalling with legacy peer deps?

Comment: Yeah I forgot, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates you have `vite@2.9.15` installed, but `@sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.454` expects `vite@^3.1.0-beta.1`.

A quick fix is to install that version of `vite` with:

```bash
npm i -D vite@^3.1.0-beta.1
```